# Export to excel in SAP WebGui using ALV

Tags: excel, web, abap, alv

I have a problem with SAP WEBGUI when I try to export my ALV in Excel file.
So I used the button Local File. When I choose

[image]

and I press confirm button, nothing happens. After this operation, any other button doesn't work.

Can you help me? I'm using WEBGUI on Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Does it work in SAP GUI itself? 
Can you look at the network traffic / console of your browser and see what happens during export?

Comment: In SAP GUI in works. How can I look no network traffic? I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

SAP has special note [314568](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/314568) concerning limitations of SAP-GUI for HTML. 
There, in particular, it is stated that:

> Excel-Export available via "XML-export" 
> Other export options **are not
>   provided** by the ALV framework in a Web environment

So use XML-export and paste its contents into Excel file.

P.S. [Here](https://subversion.renater.fr/sifacweb/docAmue/57SI-doc-formationAmue/doc%20divers/Note%20314568%20-%20SAP%20GUI%20for%20HTML%20functionality%20%20Limitations%20%20Sp.%20Behaviour.pdf) is the old version of the above note, if you have no S-user.

Comment: I have the same issue than Darko. I can't find any option as "XML-export". Where is it?